# Tool bar is not visible in custom UIViewController

Tags: ipad, xcode4, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I am creating a master detail application using monotouch for iPad. In the master view I added, a custom UIViewController. This UIViewController has a tool bar at the top and 2 UITableView. I can only see the first UITableView. I cant see the tool bar and the other UItableView at the bottom.

I am not sure if I need to turn on anything or configure anything to enable the visibility.

I created outlet for each of the table views and toolbar.

I would appreciate if anyone could shed some lights on this.

Please see the image.

[image]

Thanks

Balan Sinniah

UPDATE : I have AppDelegate code as below

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations
    UIWindow window;
    UISplitViewController splitViewController;


    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        var controller = new RootViewController ();

        var navigationController = new UITabbedViewController();
        var detailViewController = new UIDetailViewTabbedBarController();
        splitViewController = new UISplitViewController ();
        splitViewController.WeakDelegate = detailViewController;
        splitViewController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {
            navigationController,
            detailViewController
        };

        window.RootViewController = splitViewController;
        navigationController.DetailViewController = detailViewController;
        // make the window visible
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
}
```

My Navigation Controller is UITabbedView Controller which has 2 UIViewController. I am adding the toolbar and 2 Table Views in one of the UIViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by adjusting  the autosizing section in interface builder, mark the left, right and upper red lines and unmark the bottom red line, then everything looks fine to me.

I did the same for the UITableView , I umarked the red line in top.

Answer (score 1):

For the toolbar, try once to implement this on your uiviewcontroller
(it can be the other way round to (so false in the first and true in the second)

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated) {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden (true, animated);
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated) {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden (false, animated);
    }
```

For the table, are the 2 tableview listed underneath each other?
(in the viewbuilder make the first tableview less high, it will adapt to the amount of data automatically when you run the application )

Comment: It's crashing because the NavigationController is NULL. I have updated my question. This probably might tell you that I am doing something not right. Thanks

Comment: Never worked with splitviews before, but normally you have to set the navigationController as rootviewcontroller of the window, and add the mainview to this navigationcontroller, something like

window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
navcontroller = new UINavigationController ();
navcontroller.PushViewController (new SplitViewController (), false);
window.RootViewController = navcontroller;
window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
return true;